# "State pattern" vs "one member function per state"?

Tags: c++, design-patterns, pointer-to-member, state-pattern

My class has 3 states. In each state it does some work, and goes to other state, or remains in the same state (in 95% or more cases it will stay in the same state). I can implement state pattern (I assume you know it). The alternative, which I pretty like, is this:

I have a member function per state, and also a pointer to member function, which points to the current state function. When in a state I want to go to another state, I just point that function pointer to another state function. (maybe this isn't completely equivalent to state pattern, but in my case it works fine).

Those two ways are almost identical, I think.

So, my questions are:

1. Which solution is better (depends on what)?
2. Is it worth to declare a class per state (which will have only one function)? I think that would be artificial.
3. What about performance? isn't creating new object of state class (in case of state pattern) bring with it a slight overhead? (Sure state classes shouldn't have members, but anyway it should cost something)

Comment: If your code is working then CodeReview is probably the right place for it.

Comment: My question is general, isn't connected with my code.

Comment: Consider browsing/posting Programmers board then

Comment: You don't need to keep creating new objects if you're using separate classes, you can keep one of each around and switch a pointer like you're doing now. It's impossible to answer this in general, though - if your implementation suits your needs, stick to it and don't complicate thing. (A "pattern" is a means towards solving a problem, not an end in itself.)

Comment: @molbdnilo, thanks, I thought about it, but forgot at some time :)

Comment: You can demonstrate a working example of your design and ask a general question,

Comment: Thank you for suggestion, n.m., but my program is too large to demonstrate, and I don't see the need to try to make a simple case. Sorry if my question doesn't make sense for you.

Comment: @ArthurHavlicek when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really mention the constraints under which your program will run, so it's hard comment specifically about overheads of one implementation over the other, so I'll just make a comment about code maintainability.

Personally I think that unless your state machine is extremely simple and will stay simple, then declaring a class per state is far more maintainable, extensible & readable. A good rule of thumb might be that if you can't look at the code in your class and keep the entire picture in your head, then your class is probably doing too much. The small overhead you pay in declaring a class per state is likely to be well worth the productivity gains you will get from writing modular code (or anyone else who ends up maintaining it). I've come across far too many 'uber' classes that are essentially one big (very hard too maintain) state machine that probably started out as a simple state machine, to recommend otherwise.

The 'S' and 'O' portions of the SOLID acronym (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design) are always good things to keep in mind.

Comment: This is what I was thinking of, for keeping it simple I would have some overhead (like state classes will have reference to the main class, must be friend of it to access private members, etc....), but probably it makes more sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. It depends if you need to access private members of your object or not. If not, then an out-of-class implementation breaks your code in smaller fragments and may be preferable because of this (but this is non objective : the two solutions have pros and cons).
2. It's not necessary, but adds a layer of abstraction and loosen the coupling. Using an interface, you can change each implementation without affecting the others (e.g. adding class fields...)
3. Doesn't matter so much, allocating a new empty class or calling a function have same magnitude of overhead.

Comment: regarding 3, does allocation of an empty class include call of malloc? I think yes, since it should have an address (it's size is 1 not 0). So if it calls malloc, it should affect performance.

Comment: It probably does. Well, I was a bit provocative here, I went a bit away from C world and find C programmers too worried about performance of their code in places they shouldn't. 1. you said switching state was not frequent and 2. you can still use static instances like molbdnilo pointed out, so do not base your code design decision on performance worries.

Comment: Yes, in my case it doesn't affect much, and yes molbdnilo's solution was nice, but in general, we should always consider performance :)